# Why Average User Engagement Time is too high?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

We started to implement manual_screen_view for Android in June 2021. Faced problem about double screen_view events. It was fixed and released around the 12th of July. The last release before the problem appeared was on the 16th of August.

Everything was fine until the 26th of August. Since then our engagement times started to rise significantly and way out of proportion. As an example, we've highlighted a screen called "Logo intro". This is Splash screen and takes around 5 seconds before moving on to the next screen. Why is the average engagement time 1m 33s and then varies from 6mins to 40 sec.? There are way more examples, but this is a nice illustration.

[graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WeXr.png)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HkX.png)

We spoke with Firebase support and sent them screenshots from DebugView. Everything is perfectly fine with events and params. "Logo Intro" event is sent, then "Watch" event with previous "Logo Intro" and engagement_time_msec is around 6 second.

[log intro event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHKmv.png)

[watch event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBCU8.png)

[watch event previous screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2Nd.png)

[watch event engagement_time_msec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q5TJ.png)

We try to contact with Google Analytics support but haven't get any answer yet.

Comment: We have the exact same issue. We implemented manual screen tracking on both our apps (android and ios) but in android one the engagement time (average and per session) skyrocketed by 700% https://prnt.sc/3Ia6KA9dFLR7 from that release on.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to understand this metric "Average engagement time". I have start to understand that metric when I was looking for how it is counted. In GA4 interface the note in question mark is very sad. This is from docs:

`Average engagement time is the sum of user engagement durations divided by the number of active users. This metric shows the average engagement time per user. Google Analytics also shows the average engagement time per session, which is the sum of user engagement durations divided by the number of sessions.` (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11109416)

In other words, the metric doesn't say what is average time spent in the mobile app for one session. It says how long on the average the users stays in your mobile app in the time period. E.g it says this "Between 1.9.2021 and 31.12.2021 users spend with your app 6 min on average. They dedicated 6mins of their life on average with your mobile app between the time period"

Rather than looking at implementation, which seems okay to me, ask some questions:

1. Have you released any new cool feature, that your users were looking forward to?
2. What about your **average session duration**, did it change overtime? If so, how and explore why.

Comment: There is no way user can stay more than 5 seconds on splash screen. But GA4 shows 1,5 or even 5 mins. There is thread on Firebase sdk github about that https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3240

Comment: The correct docs' page for explanation is now https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10999789?hl=en